# How to resolve a Segmentation Fault in a multithreaded Rust application in Alpine WSL?

Tags: rust, windows-subsystem-for-linux, alpine-linux, rust-tokio

If I run `cargo install-update --list` I get a `Segmentation fault`.

I've noticed the same if I run my CLI applications which use tokio runtime and have network requests with `reqwest`.
If I run `cargo install <package>` that works fine. Meaning CLI applications can access the network.

This is happening in Alpine Linux install in WSL 2 on Windows.

dmesg shows

```
[54391.796247] cargo-install-u[11344]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000000000 sp 00007ffdf8e9c398 error 14
[54391.797248] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0xffffffffffffffd6.
[54391.797847] potentially unexpected fatal signal 11.
[54391.798251] CPU: 7 PID: 11344 Comm: cargo-install-u Not tainted 5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1
[54391.798906] RIP: 0033:0x0
[54391.799192] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0xffffffffffffffd6.
[54391.799659] RSP: 002b:00007ffdf8e9c398 EFLAGS: 00010246
[54391.799957] RAX: 00007f40fe395b20 RBX: 00007f40fe3bf480 RCX: 00007ffdf8e9c458
[54391.800407] RDX: 00007ffdf8e9c460 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000280000
```

Any hints would be appreciated. I am not sure how to troubleshoot and where to address the problem - whether it is WSL, Alpine Linux, Rust, Tokio, reqwest or somewhere else.

Cargo version: `cargo 1.66.0 (d65d197ad 2022-11-15)`

Cargo-Update version: `cargo-update v11.0.0`

Comment: What version of `cargo` and `cargo-update` are you using? Are you aware that vanilla [`cargo install` will now upgrade as well](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/6798)?

Comment: Thanks, @Pitaj. I've added the versions to the question. I noticed that `install` now installs a new version, but `install-update` shows which crates are outdated.

Comment: Can you try re-installing `cargo-update`?

Comment: Alright, just did. No changes. Also please note the 2nd sentence in the post. Other apps also fail.

Answer (score 2):

The [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65053259/reqwest-segmentation-fault-from-aws-lambda-with-rust) (thanks, SO!) provides a useful hint about the OpenSSL dependency on Linux systems.

Indeed, following the answer there and using `rusttls`

```
reqwest = { version = "0.11.13", default-features = false, features = ["json", "rustls-tls"] }
```

instead of the default native-tls, fixes the issue.

The [reqwest docs](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.13/reqwest/) list OpenSSL (1.1) as a requirement on Linux. Alpine contains v3 packages with 1.1 compatibility packages but I'm not sure which ones should be installed or if they are by default.

So, hopefully there would be an option to install whatever necessary package and not to have to change the app dependencies.

In this case I could fix my app that had the Segfault but that won't work for others, like `cargo-update` for example.